# Import shadowed module into shadowing module which is in sys.path

Tags: python, python-module

There are similar questions about importing an intentionally shadowed module into a shadowing module which is **not** in `sys.path`. That's pretty easy; just use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Here's my problem: my module **is** in `sys.path`, **and** it's higher up in `sys.path`, **and** that's intentional!

To be more specific, I'm writing a python interpreter which lacks access to `stdin`, but it can use `Tkinter`. Not having access to `stdin` means I can't just use normal `input`, `raw_input`, and `getpass`. I need to replace those with my own methods. The first two are rather easy to handle - I just replace them in `__builtin__`. `getpass` isn't as easy though - the user may or may not import it, but when they do, I need to make sure that what they actually import is my module, not the standard one, so that I can get their input through a `Tkinter` `Entry` instead of `stdin`. That part I have handled. The part that I can't figure out is how to pass everything else through to the standard `getpass`, IE, `getuser()` should be handled by the real `getpass`.

Here's what I tried:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
pathToThisGetpass = sys.path.pop(1)    # I know that the shadowing getpass is at index 1.
import getpass as realGetpass          # Since the path doesn't contain this getpass, this should be the real one, right?
sys.path.insert(1, pathToThisGetpass)  # Put this getpass module back into the path again

def getuser():
    print("I am " + str(getuser))
    print("I should call " + str(realGetpass.getuser))
    return realGetpass.getuser()
```

I added in those two print statements just so I could see why `getuser()` was failing, and I found that it would print this:

```
I am <function getuser at 0x026D8A30>
I should call <function getuser at 0x026D8A30>
```

Plus I end up with infinite recursion.

So... any ideas how I can resolve this?

To try reproducing this, write a file like the one I have above, name it `getpass.py`, then add the folder that contains it to your `sys.path`, then run:

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [`imp.load_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module)?

Comment: @9000 - I have not. Would that work for me? I read the documentation you linked to and it seems a bit confusing. Care to give a working example as an answer?

Comment: @9000 - Namely, I'm confused as to how I would be able to access the shadowed `getpass` if I went that route - it doesn't have anything like the `as` part of `import ... as ...` that would allow me to refer to it by a different name.

Comment: If you somehow know the path of the file to import (e.g. by searching at `sys.path` on your own), you can just open that file, say something like `shadow_getpass = imp.load_module('shadowed.getpass', that_open_file, '', ('', 'r', imp.PY_COMPILED))`, and `that_open_file.close()`. Then use `shadow_getpass` as you would a normal module. (I assume you'll use `getpass.pyc`, so `PY_COMPILED`.)

Comment: Okay, so I replaced `import getpass as realGetpass` in my original code above with `realGetpass = imp.load_module('getpass', *imp.find_module('getpass'))` and now it seems to work. If you post an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comments posted as an answer:)

Use [`imp.load_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) and load the module you want, ignoring the standard search.

If you somehow learn the path of the file to import (e.g. by searching at `sys.path` on your own), you can just open that file, say something like

```
with open(off_path_name) as shadowed_module_file:
  shadow_getpass = imp.load_module(
      'shadowed.getpass',    # the name reported by the module, rather arbitrary
      shadowed_module_file,  # where we are reading it from
      '', # we don't plan to reload this module normally, no suffix
      ('', 'r', imp.PY_COMPILED) # Assuming it's getpass.pyc, use PY_COMPILED
  )
```

Then use `shadow_getpass` as you would a normal module.

Error-handling is omitted, but it's not hard to catch appropriate exceptions.